# Django - Deleting instance according a user's choice in a table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following situation: At the user's area on the website he can see all his real estate posts in a table. There is a "trash button" for each one of the posts. When he press the button I want do delete from DB the exact instance he choose.

[image: user's area]
This is the HTML that I have. Please note that I used an   to use a view to access the DB and then delete from DB. But I don't know how to send the exactly parameters to find it on the DB.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Olá, {{ request.user.first_name }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 custyle">
    <table class="table table-striped custab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Imagem Principal</th>
            <th>Data Criação</th>
            <th>Tipo do Anúncio</th>
            <th>Tipo do Imóvel</th>
            <th>Preço Venda</th>
            <th>Visualizações</th>
            <th>Expira</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
            {% for anuncio in anuncios %}
            <tr >
                <td>
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <img class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{anuncio.imagem_principal.url}}">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Falta</td>
                <td>{{anuncio.tipo_anuncio}}</td>
                <td>{{anuncio.tipo_imovel}}</td>
                <td>R$ {{anuncio.preco_venda}}</td>
                <td>Falta</td>
                <td>News Cate</td>
                <td>News Cate</td>
                <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </button></p>
                </td>


            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

    </table>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Edit Your Detail</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Mohsin">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Irshad">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="CB 106/107 Street # 11 Wah Cantt Islamabad Pakistan"></textarea>


        </div>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Update</button>
      </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
  </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>



    <div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Delete this entry</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

       <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Are you sure you want to delete this Record?</div>

      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer form-actions">
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard:dashboard_deletar' %}" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No</button>
      </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
  </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>
```

I am practing what I learnt in a book, so I don't want to go for AJAX yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the button inside of a `<form>` that `POST`s to a view, which will then delete the instance. For example:

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_estate %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="estate_id" value="{{ estate.id }}">
</form>
```

**view**

```
def delete_estate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        estate_id = request.POST['estate_id']
        estate = Estate.objects.get(id=estate_id)
        estate.delete()

        messages.success(request, "Estate deleted successfully!")
        return redirect("/")
```

**urls**

```
...
url(r'^delete-estate/$', views.delete_estate.as_view(), name='delete_estate'),
....
```

Comment: Sorry, but is does not work in this case. There is a modal dialog after clicking the trash button. That is my problem. I don't know how to take the post_id to this dialog. If was only the button without a confirmation it would be okay to do what you propposed.

Answer (score 1):

Put the modal inside of the for loop as well so that there is a distinct modal for every estate. Remember to change the id of the modal to something like `id="delete_{{ anuncio.id }}"` and have the delete button activate that same modal using `data-target="delete_{{ anuncio.id }}"`. From within that modal you should be able to do what Hybrid said with the form and access the {{ anuncio.id }} variable.

If you didn't already know, id is already created by default.